# How do you move user input from one activity to another activities listview

Tags: android

I am using an SQLite database and trying to put info into the database, but into a listview at the same time, is this possible?

Comment: Is your data in an Object or is it just a String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you pass variable to another activity as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra('keyName', 'data');
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in AnotherActivity you acces them as

```
getStringExtra(String keyName)
```

Then you can populate your listview in new activity.

Comment: Thanks! I have got this far, I just didn't know exactly how to populate the list view with the variable, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

To pass values between activities, All you need to do is to bind the values to intent in source activity and retrieve them back at the target activity or somewhere else you need